# Tedious Styling Bug with MS Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

I have a number of reports that display dates in the UK format. I need to change these to display dates in the Japanese format. I've changed the LANGUAGE to be ja-jp and the report looks fine when I preview it in Visual Studio 2008. However, when I upload it to the server and come to view it the styling has gone and the date isn't formatting.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing or have overlooked?

Comment: What happens if you sneak in a textbox with [`=User!Language`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281090%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)? The server may be executing the report in an unexpected locale?

Comment: Also: how are you "viewing it"? On a website with a ReportViewer, through a Sharepoint portal, via a Webservice, in the web management interface?

Comment: Hello Jeroen, I'm viewing the reports via the 'Reports' website. I'm using the external URL not the localhost on the DBServer. Is this the web management interface? I'm not viewing it via SharePoint nor via a webservice.

Comment: Note that you can edit your question to add details, new visitors to this question may not read all comments.

Comment: [This MSDN page on language in SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156493(v=sql.105).aspx) may be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two solutions to this. The first involved moving the text box. I had a text box at the top of the report. When I changed its language to ja-jp then the appearance of the table beneath was affected. Moving the text box below the table prevented this from happening. It sounds a bit ridiculous but it worked.

The other involved editing the actual RDL file. Instead of specifying the language I edited the FORMAT tag within the STYLE tag

```
<Format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:m</Format>
```